# Is it possible for a human being to travel at the speed of light?

Tags: speed-of-light

Can our human body travel at the speed of light in a space shuttle? Indeed, can any material object with nonzero mass travel at the speed of light with respect to a valid inertial frame? If not, why not?

Comment: Just check the other questions and answers to with the [tag:faster-than-light] tag

Comment: You did not specify the reference frame. So in principle yes, we can have a relative speed c respect to any photon. So we can travel at the speed of light (only) respect to the light (photos).

Comment: @Idear I don't really think that is a useful kind of thing to say: it is rather likely to cause confusion in beginners and in any case photons don't have well defined rest frames. While it is possible to do lQCD "on the lightcone" this is still a pretty special case defined in terms of a limit.

Answer (score 1):

For anything to travel at the speed of light, without the use of a theoretical wormhole etc. You would need an infinite amount of energy, because as we know, when an object begins to gain speed, it's weight increases and becomes heavier, therefore we would need more energy to maintain the increase in speed until we reach the speed of light.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, nothing can travel faster than light. So the space shuttle will not be able to attain a speed of light or a speed faster than light. Even if it is able to attain that speed, we cannot just simply sit in that space shuttle and we will require a lot of protection and cushioning.